# Controlling the radial derivative by vector fields

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Given a smooth and compactly supported function $u(t,x)$, do we have
$|r\partial_ru| \lesssim|Su| + |u|+ |\nabla_x u|+|\partial_tu|+ \sum |\Omega_{ij} u| $ where $\Omega_{ij} = (x_i \partial_j-x_j\partial_i)_{1 \leq i < j \leq 3}$, in three spatial dimensions?

The definition of $r\partial_r u$ is $r\partial_r u = \sum_{j=1}^3x_j \partial_j u$, and $Su = r\partial_ru+t\partial_tu$.

Edit: Let us assume that at time $t$, the function $u(t,x)$ is supported inside $\{|x| \leq t\}$. Thanks to F. Conrad.

Comment: If it is compactly supported in time as well (say in $[0,T_{max}]$), you have $ |r \partial_r u| =|r \partial_r u \pm t \partial_t u|  \leq |Su| +|t\partial_t u| \leq |Su|+T_{max}|\partial_t u| $. I think it is an interesting question if one would require not-compactly supported in time, but in space only.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Yes, the situation I had in mind was not compactly supported in time, but that for each t, $u$ is compactly supported in space. Say $u(t,x)$ is supported within $\{|x| \leq t \}$.

Comment: Are $x_i$ specifically the standard basis coordinates or are they supposed to represent any smooth coordinate system?

Comment: When I wrote the question I was thinking of the standard basis coordinates.